# Extended font-face in I.E. 5

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I have a css which is using external font called as `OCR.A.Extended`. Now I have to make this font supported in I.E. 5 but it is not supporting whereas in higher versions of I.E., its is displaying fine. I am using following css..

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: OCR;
        src: url(../OCR.A.Extended.woff); 
        src: url(../OCR.A.Extended.woff) format("opentype");
    }
```

Do I need to go with some other file format except `.woff` like `.eot` or `.SVG`
Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: ie5?  who's still using ie5?

Comment: IE 5? Is this a joke?

Comment: but to answer your question, ie6 used the `.eot` font with the `#iefix` hack - not sure if ie5 supported font-face as it was quite a non-standard browser (leading to the birth of quirks mode for ie6)

Comment: @Pete I will try with .eot and let you know

Comment: @Pete `.eot` worked..Thnks

Comment: @Pete These things happen. I'm currently tasked with maintaining a web application that only runs correctly in IE5 compatibility mode. Not in any other browser.